# stopwords in sentence tokenizer

Tags: python, nlp

i am using stopwords and sentence tokenizer but when i print filtered sentence that gives me result including stopwords. the problem is it not ignore stopwords in output . how to remove stopwords in sentence tokenizer ?

```
 userinput1  = input ("Enter file name:")
    myfile1 = open(userinput1).read()
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))
    word1 = nltk.sent_tokenize(myfile1)
    filtration_sentence = []
    for w in word1:
        word = sent_tokenize(myfile1)
        filtered_sentence = [w for w in word if not w in stop_words]
        print(filtered_sentence)

    userinput2  = input ("Enter file name:")
    myfile2 = open(userinput2).read()
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))
    word2 = nltk.sent_tokenize(myfile2)
    filtration_sentence = []
    for w in word2:
        word = sent_tokenize(myfile2)
        filtered_sentence = [w for w in word if not w in stop_words]
        print(filtered_sentence)

    stemmer = nltk.stem.porter.PorterStemmer()
    remove_punctuation_map = dict((ord(char), None) for char in string.punctuation)

    def stem_tokens(tokens):
        return [stemmer.stem(item) for item in tokens]

    '''remove punctuation, lowercase, stem'''
    def normalize(text):
        return stem_tokens(nltk.sent_tokenize(text.lower().translate(remove_punctuation_map)))
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=normalize, stop_words='english')

    def cosine_sim(myfile1, myfile2):
        tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform([myfile1, myfile2])
        return ((tfidf * tfidf.T).A)[0,1]
    print(cosine_sim(myfile1,myfile2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cannot directly remove `stopwords` from the sentence. You have to split each words in sentences out first or using `nltk.word_tokenize` to split your sentences. The for each words, you check if it's in the stop words list. Here is an example:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopwords_en = set(stopwords.words('english'))

sents = nltk.sent_tokenize("This is an example sentence. We will remove stop words from this")

sents_rm_stopwords = []
for sent in sents:
    sents_rm_stopwords.append(' '.join(w for w in nltk.word_tokenize(sent) if w.lower() not in stopwords_en))
```

**Output**

```
['example sentence .', 'remove stop words']
```

**note** that you can also remove punctuation using `string.punctuation`.

```
import string
stopwords_punctuation = stopwords_en.union(string.punctuation) # merge set together
```

Comment: how to use string.punctuation ? @titipata

Comment: `import string` and `string.punctuation`, then you can do `stopwords_en.union(string.punctuation)`.

Comment: ok i am trying to implement this . one more problem . my code above will give cosine similarity between two documents but i want it will show the similarity sentence between two documents.. how can i print them ?@titipata

Comment: Oh boy, that's a harder question tho. You can do tfidf cosine distance between documents. However, for sentence similarity, you can either calculate Jaccard distance between words in sentences or tfidf vectors similarity then rank the most similar pair to least. There are a lot of choices you can do about that...